# how to get value from dependant drop down list to javascript and parsing it to another php page?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I make a 2 level dependant drop down list and that work fine, but I don't know how to get the 2nd level value with javascript..here is the code I'm using..

dropdownlist.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dropdown_list.js"></script>
<select class="level" id="level1" onChange="get_level2(this.value)">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">--Choose One--</option>

<?php
$sql_get = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM ajax_table WHERE pid=0");

    while($row_get = mysql_fetch_array($sql_get))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$row_get['id']."'>".$row_get['category']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <span id="level2"></span>
```

since the dependant work just fine..so I think I can skip the `get_level2 ()` function and another php file to process the 2nd level drop down..

and here is the code where I try to get the value from drop down list when button click..

dropdown_list.js :

```
function cekForm() {
//the getValue1 work fine but I can't make getValue2 work..
//how to get value from 2nd level drop down list with getValue2??

var value1 = document.getElementById("level1");
var getValue1 = value1.options[value1.selectedIndex].value;
var value2 = document.getElementById("level2");
var getValue2 = value2.options[value2.selectedIndex].value;
if (getValue1 == 0){
alert("Please Choose One");
}
if (getValue1 != 0){
//where I want to pass the dropdown value to post_value.php
window.location= "post_value.php";
}
}
```

How to get the value of 2nd level drop down list??and how to pass the value to post_value.php??

please help me...

**Update :**

Here is the code from firefox view page source:

```
//this is <head> part
  <link href="../css/val.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dropdown_list.js"></script>
//end of </head>

//<body> part
<div class="form-div">
    <form id="form_level" name="form_level" style="padding-top:0px;">
    <div class="form-row" style="padding-top:0px;">
    <h3>Choose Drop Down :</h3>
    <select class="level" id="level1" onChange="get_level2(this.value)" style="position:relative; top:-40px; left:150px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">--Choose One--</option>
    <option value='1'>BAA</option><option value='2'>BAK</option><option value='3'>BAUK</option></select>

    <span id="level2"></span>
    </div>


      <div class="form-row" style="position:relative; top:100px; left:305px;">
      <input class="submit" value="Send" type="button" onClick="cekForm()">
      </div>
      <br /><br />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could also post the "final" HTML code, the way it appears in the browser's "show source" code. It would help understand what the function you're trying to make is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass value using get method through url

```
<script>
function cekForm() {

    var getValue1 = document.getElementById("level1").value;
    var getValue2 = document.getElementById("level2").getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;

    if (getValue1.length==0){
        alert("Please Choose One");
        return;
    }
    if (getValue1.length>0){
        window.location= "post_value.php?level1="+getValue1+"&level2="+getValue2;
    }
}
</script>
```

and receive it in php file

**post_value.php**

```
<?php

$level1 = $_GET["level1"];
$level2 = $_GET["level2"];

?>
```

Comment: with your code it only works for getValue1 but when I insert the getValue2 part, the onclik button will show no response...
Why is that??

Comment: @reza: I have seen in your code first <span id="level2"></span>. But in updated code it is <span id="layanan2"></span> why. just replace level2 by layanan2 in line as var getValue2 = document.getElementById("layanan2").getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value; and send me you feedback again

Comment: sorry my bad..my sleepy eye do wrong typo...It's `<span id="level2"></span>` i will edit the post..and i try using `var getValue2 = document.getElementById("level2").getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;` but still not working..any other method??please... I still stuck in this problem